# Use cases of different Salesforce APIs

Tags: apex, rest-api, metadata-api, tooling-api

I wanted to understand in what scenarios we can use the below APIs:

1. Metadata API
2. Tooling API
3. UI-API
4. Composite API
5. REST API

Its very confusing if we are checking from the documentation. What could be the different use cases of using these APIs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Salesforce, we have two general types of data: *data*, and *metadata*. Data are individual records, such as an Account record, or a User record. Metadata is configuration that describes the "shape" of data records and the organization, including fields, relationships, page layouts, code, and pretty much everything else you see in Salesforce's Setup menu.

## Metadata API

An API for *System Administrator* users to migrate **metadata** between organizations. Requires Customize Application permission in order to use this. Cannot be used to direct affect **data** (though some API calls could update many records, such as deleting a field).

## Tooling API

An API for "Salesforce Developer" users to create, update, and delete a limited subtype of **metadata** related to developing Salesforce apps. Requires some administrator permissions in order to use this. This API cannot be used to update **data**. Also provides an interface to run an "anonymous script" for one-off Apex Code operations without deploying any changes to an org.

## UI-API

An API primarily designed for Lightning Experience to provide a complete User Interface to create and edit **data**, and provides read-only **metadata** for records. Available for all users with Lightning Experience, meant to be used by Lightning Components that render a UI based on record and user configuration and permissions. Requires only minimal permissions to use.

## REST API

A general API intended to create/update/delete **data** and provides *read-only* access to **metadata**. Meant primarily for custom mobile apps. Requires minimal permissions in order to use. Can be used instead of the UI-API. It's a more general-purpose API than the UI-API.

## Composite API

A general JSON-based API that allows multiple REST-based API calls in a single transaction. Because Salesforce limits [how many API calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) you can use a day, this API is meant to provide more functionality in fewer calls. You can generally use this API as a way to optimize REST API calls. Other types of APIs are not available with the Composite API. This API is meant for **data** transactions.

## SOAP API

The original API, built on SOAP (an XML-based protocol) to allow users to create/modify/delete **data**, and provides *read-only* access to **metadata**. Requires minimal permissions in order to use. This was the original API meant to design apps that users could use, as well as server-to-server integration. For example, the Apex Data Loader uses this API to create/update/delete records.

---

There are other APIs that Salesforce has as well, such as an Internet of Things API for connecting to special devices, such as routers or printers, Chatter API for allowing users to communicate with each other and uploading files, etc.

I hope that this answer provides enough information for you to get started. Just be aware that there are many different types of APIs, and their documentation generally provides information in the first few pages.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks for explaining it so well!